# how to authorize SignalR Hub in WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I create a ASP.NET WebApi project, it use `[Authorize]` attribute to authorize controllers, such as:

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles="Users, Admins")]
public ValueController : ApiController
{
     [HttpGet]
     public string GetValue()
     {
         return "Hello World !";
     }
}
```

now I want to add Signalr to this project. This is what I did:

In App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs, add following codes in `ConfigureAuth()` function to start SignalR.

```
app.Map(signalr, map =
{
    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
    {
    };

    hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
     map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
});
```

Then I add a MessageHub, trying to allow authorized user to send messages to all clients:

```
[Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Authorize]
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.SendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

if I start this project, type http://localhost:4000/signalr/hubs in browser, I can receive a hubs js.

**Q1** - For me that means SignalR is working on my WebApi project, right?

now I need to test SendMessage, first thing I did is login through http://localhost:4000/Token, then get an access_token. In webApi I usually put this token in Header:

```
Authorization : Bearer access_token
```

to access APIs.

**Q2** - now what should I do with this token to access MessageHub?